# What does opening a file actually do?

Tags: c, linux

In all programming languages (that I use at least), you must open a file before you can read or write to it.

But what does this open operation actually do?

Manual pages for typical functions dont actually tell you anything other than it 'opens a file for reading/writing':

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Obviously, through usage of the function you can tell it involves creation of some kind of object which facilitates accessing a file.

Another way of putting this would be, if I were to implement an `open` function, what would it need to do on Linux?

Comment: Editing this question to focus on `C` and Linux; since what Linux and Windows do differs.  Otherwise, it's a bit too broad.  Also, any higher level language will end up calling either a C API for the system or compiling down to C to execute, so leaving at the level of "C" is putting it at the Least Common Denominator.

Comment: Not to mention that not _all_ programming languages have this facility, or it is a facility that is highly dependent on environment. Admittedly rare these days, of course, but to this day file handling is a completely optional part of ANSI Forth, and wasn't even present in some implementations in the past.

Answer (score 195):

In almost every high-level language, the function that opens a file is a wrapper around the corresponding kernel system call. It may do other fancy stuff as well, but in contemporary operating systems, opening a file must always go through the kernel.

This is why the arguments of the `fopen` library function, or Python's `open` closely resemble the arguments of the `open(2)` system call.

In addition to opening the file, these functions usually set up a buffer that will be consequently used with the read/write operations. The purpose of this buffer is to ensure that whenever you want to read N bytes, the corresponding library call will return N bytes, regardless of whether the calls to the underlying system calls return less.

> I am not actually interested in implementing my own function; just in understanding what the hell is going on...'beyond the language' if you like.

In Unix-like operating systems, a successful call to `open` returns a "file descriptor" which is merely an integer in the context of the user process. This descriptor is consequently passed to any call that interacts with the opened file, and after calling `close` on it, the descriptor becomes invalid.

It is important to note that the call to `open` acts like a validation point at which various checks are made. If not all of the conditions are met, the call fails by returning `-1` instead of the descriptor, and the kind of error is indicated in `errno`. The essential checks are:

- Whether the file exists;
- Whether the calling process is privileged to open this file in the specified mode. This is determined by matching the file permissions, owner ID and group ID to the respective ID's of the calling process.

In the context of the kernel, there has to be some kind of mapping between the process' file descriptors and the physically opened files. The internal data structure that is mapped to the descriptor may contain yet another buffer that deals with block-based devices, or an internal pointer that points to the current read/write position.

Comment: It is worth noting that in Unix-like OSes, the in-kernel structure file descriptors are mapped to, is called "open file description". So process FDs are mapped to kernel OFDs. This is important to understand the documentation. For instance, see `man dup2` and check the subtlety between a _open file descriptor_ (that is a FD that happens to be open) and a _open file description_ (a OFD).

Comment: And that's it? Nothing minor, like checking you are actually allowed to open the file?

Comment: Yes, permissions are checked at open time. You can go and read the source for the kernel's "open" implementation: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c although it delegates most of the work to the specific file system driver.

Comment: (on ext2 systems this will involve reading the directory entries to identify which inode has the metadata in, then loading that inode into the inode cache. Note that there may be pseudofilesystems like "/proc" and "/sys" which may do arbitrary things when you open a file)

Comment: Note that the checks on file open -- that the file exists, that you have permission -- are, in practice, not sufficient.  The file can disappear, or its permissions can change, under your feet.  Some file systems attempt to prevent this, but so long as your OS supports network storage it is impossible to prevent (an OS can "panic" if the local file system misbehaves and be reasonable: one that does so when a network share does is not a viable OS).  Those checks are *also* done at file open, but must (effectively) be done at all other file access as well.

Comment: Not to forget evaluation and/or creation of locks. These can be shared, or exclusive and can affect the whole file, or only a part of it.

Comment: @Yakk: For local filesystems, the check for existence at open time is usually sufficient: even if the file's name is removed from the directory, the file itself will (on most Unix-type systems) continue to exist until it is closed.

Comment: @psmears yes, and if the file system behaves sufficiently badly, the OS panicing & going down is considered reasonable.  Hence the open-gives-errors approach, and read-just-works approach.  I'm just pointing out that this approach doesn't work in the general case, and lots of bugs happen because of the assumption that file systems behave that way.  Even locally, disks can fail in the middle of a file being "open"; robust file access that doesn't presume file system stability can make that "not a problem".

Answer (score 94):

I'd suggest you take a look at [this guide through a simplified version of the `open()` system call](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/vfs/trail-2.html). It uses the following code snippet, which is representative of what happens behind the scenes when you open a file.

```
0  int sys_open(const char *filename, int flags, int mode) {
1      char *tmp = getname(filename);
2      int fd = get_unused_fd();
3      struct file *f = filp_open(tmp, flags, mode);
4      fd_install(fd, f);
5      putname(tmp);
6      return fd;
7  }
```

Briefly, here's what that code does, line by line:

1. Allocate a block of kernel-controlled memory and copy the filename into it from user-controlled memory.
2. Pick an unused file descriptor, which you can think of as an integer index into a growable list of currently open files. Each process has its own such list, though it's maintained by the kernel; your code can't access it directly. An entry in the list contains whatever information the underlying filesystem will use to pull bytes off the disk, such as inode number, process permissions, open flags, and so on.
3. The `filp_open` function has the implementation

   ```
   struct file *filp_open(const char *filename, int flags, int mode) {
           struct nameidata nd;
           open_namei(filename, flags, mode, &nd);
           return dentry_open(nd.dentry, nd.mnt, flags);
   }
   ```

   which does two things:

   1. Use the filesystem to look up the inode (or more generally, whatever sort of internal identifier the filesystem uses) corresponding to the filename or path that was passed in.
   2. Create a `struct file` with the essential information about the inode and return it. This struct becomes the entry in that list of open files that I mentioned earlier.
4. Store ("install") the returned struct into the process's list of open files.
5. Free the allocated block of kernel-controlled memory.
6. Return the file descriptor, which can then be passed to file operation functions like `read()`, `write()`, and `close()`. Each of these will hand off control to the kernel, which can use the file descriptor to look up the corresponding file pointer in the process's list, and use the information in that file pointer to actually perform the reading, writing, or closing.

If you're feeling ambitious, you can compare this simplified example to the implementation of the `open()` system call in the Linux kernel, a function called [`do_sys_open()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c?id=refs/tags/v4.3#n1010). You shouldn't have any trouble finding the similarities.

---

Of course, this is only the "top layer" of what happens when you call `open()` - or more precisely, it's the highest-level piece of kernel code that gets invoked in the process of opening a file. A high-level programming language might add additional layers on top of this. There's a lot that goes on at lower levels. (Thanks to [Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673852/ruslan) and [pjc50](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108719/pjc50) for explaining.) Roughly, from top to bottom:

- `open_namei()` and `dentry_open()` invoke filesystem code, which is also part of the kernel, to access metadata and content for files and directories. The [filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/filesystems.html) reads raw bytes from the disk and interprets those byte patterns as a tree of files and directories.
- The filesystem uses the [block device layer](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch13), again part of the kernel, to obtain those raw bytes from the drive. (Fun fact: Linux lets you access raw data from the block device layer using `/dev/sda` and the like.)
- The block device layer invokes a storage device driver, which is also kernel code, to translate from a medium-level instruction like "read sector X" to individual [input/output instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/6jct9o0aj/index.html) in machine code. There are several types of storage device drivers, including [IDE](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/ide), [(S)ATA](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/ata), [SCSI](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi), [Firewire](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/firewire), and so on, corresponding to the different communication standards that a drive could use. (Note that the naming is a mess.)
- The I/O instructions use the built-in capabilities of the processor chip and the motherboard controller to send and receive electrical signals on the wire going to the physical drive. This is hardware, not software.
- On the other end of the wire, the disk's firmware (embedded control code) interprets the electrical signals to spin the platters and move the heads (HDD), or read a flash ROM cell (SSD), or whatever is necessary to access data on that type of storage device.

This may also be [somewhat incorrect due to caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). :-P Seriously though, there are many details that I've left out - a person (not me) could write multiple books describing how this whole process works. But that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 68):

*Any file system or operating system you want to talk about is fine by me.* Nice!

---

On a ZX Spectrum, initializing a `LOAD` command will put the system into a tight loop, reading the Audio In line.

Start-of-data is indicated by a constant tone, and after that a sequence of long/short pulses follow, where a short pulse is for a binary `0` and a longer one for a binary `1` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum_software). The tight load loop gathers bits until it fills a byte (8 bits), stores this into memory, increases the memory pointer, then loops back to scan for more bits.

Typically, the first thing a loader would read is a short, fixed format *header*, indicating at least the number of bytes to expect, and possibly additional information such as file name, file type and loading address. After reading this short header, the program could decide whether to continue loading the main bulk of the data, or exit the loading routine and display an appropriate message for the user.

An End-of-file state could be recognized by receiving as many bytes as expected (either a fixed number of bytes, hardwired in the software, or a variable number such as indicated in a header). An error was thrown if the loading loop did not receive a pulse in the expected frequency range for a certain amount of time.

---

*A little background on this answer*

The procedure described loads data from a regular audio tape - hence the need to scan Audio In (it connected with a standard plug to tape recorders). A `LOAD` command is technically the same as `open` a file - but it's physically tied to *actually* loading the file. This is because the tape recorder is not controlled by the computer, and you cannot (successfully) open a file but not load it.

The "tight loop" is mentioned because (1) the CPU, a Z80-A (if memory serves), was really slow: 3.5 MHz, and (2) the Spectrum had no internal clock! That means that it had to accurately keep count of the *T-states* (instruction times) for every. single. instruction. inside that loop, just to maintain the accurate beep timing.
Fortunately, that low CPU speed had the distinct advantage that you could calculate the number of cycles on a piece of paper, and thus the real world time that they would take.

Comment: @BillWoodger: well yes. But it's a fair question (I mean yours). I voted to close as "too broad", and my answer is meant to illustrate how extremely broad the question actually is.

Comment: Well, you *almost* get a vote for that. I had a ZX-80. Did it do roughly the same :-)

Comment: I think you are broading the answer a bit too much. ZX Spectrum had an OPEN command, and that was totally different from LOAD. And harder to understand.

Comment: @rodrigo: it had? I was never happy about 'loading data' as it was too much of a hassle, what with the constant rewinding and all. I tried to locate a real ZX Spectrum BASIC manual to verify my information but could not find one at short notice.

Comment: @Jongware: Well, I remember well my paper manual, because about 25 years ago I wondered the very same question than the OP (no SO back then _sigh_). I cannot find it either in the Internet, but take a look at [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinclair_BASIC), in particular the `OPEN#` and `CLOSE#` commands.

Comment: It's not everyday I learn something new (old?) and interesting. Thank you sir :-)   ..and yes, I believe this is a perfect answer to a broad (but in my opinion, not _too_ broad) question.

Comment: This answer is pure gold. And it has a lot of pedagogical value, so it is actually useful for the OP. For me has a lot of nostalgic value as well...

Comment: Although I edited my question to restrict to linux/windows OS in attempt to keep it open, this answer is entirely valid and useful. As stated in my question, I am not looking to implement something or to get other people to do my work, I am looking to learn. To learn you must ask the 'big' questions. If we constantly close questions on SO for being 'too broad', it risks becoming a place to just get people to write your code for your without giving any explanation of what, where or why. I'd rather keep it as a place I can come to learn.

Comment: @jramm: thanks for weighing in on the discussion! My problem with the question is that it does not concern a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" or similar (as outlined in the [help/on-topic]). If you want to ask more about this, you are **welcome to open a discussion on [meta]**. Make sure to put forward your very best argumentation.

Comment: This answer seems to prove that *your* interpretation of the question is too broad, rather than that the question itself is too broad.

Comment: @jwg: it indeed may be. But I'm logically bound to see my own interpretation only. However, I am fully open to discussing this particular question on [meta] and read the points of view of others. One of my favorite movie quotes is the challenge in *Kinky Boots*: "Change your mind about someone."

Comment: Incidentally, the Spectrum is still used in the demo scene. I saw a remake of Second Reality on the Sinclair at a demo party five years ago.

Answer (score 19):

It depends on the operating system what exactly happens when you open a file. Below I describe what happens in Linux as it gives you an idea what happens when you open a file and you could check the source code if you are interested in more detail. I am not covering permissions as it would make this answer too long.

In Linux every file is recognised by a structure called [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#Implications). Each structure has an unique number and every file only gets one inode number. This structure stores meta data for a file, for example file-size, file-permissions, time stamps and pointer to disk blocks, however, not the actual file name itself. Each file (and directory) contains a file name entry and the inode number for lookup. When you open a file, assuming you have the relevant permissions, a file descriptor is created using the unique inode number associated with file name. As many processes/applications can point to the same file, inode has a link field that maintains the total count of links to the file. If a file is present in a directory, its link count is one, if it has a hard link its link count will be two and if a file is opened by a process, the link count will be incremented by 1.

Comment: What does this have to do with the actual question?

Comment: It describes what happens at a low level when you open a file in Linux. I agree the question is rather broad, so this may not have been the answer jramm was looking for.

Comment: So again, no checking for permissions?

Answer (score 14):

Bookkeeping, mostly. This includes various checks like "Does the file exist?" and "Do I have the permissions to open this file for writing?".

But that's all kernel stuff - unless you're implementing your own toy OS, there isn't much to delve into (if you are, have fun - it's a great learning experience). Of course, you should still learn all the possible error codes you can receive while opening a file, so that you can handle them properly - but those are usually nice little abstractions.

The most important part on the code level is that it gives you a *handle* to the open file, which you use for all of the other operations you do with a file. Couldn't you use the filename instead of this arbitrary handle? Well, sure - but using a handle gives you some advantages:

- The system can keep track of all the files that are currently open, and prevent them from being deleted (for example).
- Modern OSs are built around handles - there's tons of useful things you can do with handles, and all the different kinds of handles behave almost identically. For example, when an asynchronous I/O operation completes on a Windows file handle, the handle is signalled - this allows you to block on the handle until it's signalled, or to complete the operation entirely asynchronously. Waiting on a file handle is exactly the same as waiting on a thread handle (signalled e.g. when the thread ends), a process handle (again, signalled when the process ends), or a socket (when some asynchronous operation completes). Just as importantly, handles are owned by their respective processes, so when a process is terminated unexpectedly (or the application is poorly written), the OS knows what handles it can release.
- Most operations are positional - you `read` from the last position in your file. By using a handle to identify a particular "opening" of a file, you can have multiple concurrent handles to the same file, each reading from their own places. In a way, the handle acts as a moveable window into the file (and a way to issue asynchronous I/O requests, which are very handy).
- Handles are *much* smaller than file names. A handle is usually the size of a pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes. On the other hand, filenames can have hundreds of bytes.
- Handles allow the OS to *move* the file, even though applications have it open - the handle is still valid, and it still points to the same file, even though the file name has changed.

There's also some other tricks you can do (for example, share handles between processes to have a communication channel *without* using a physical file; on unix systems, files are also used for devices and various other virtual channels, so this isn't strictly necessary), but they aren't really tied to the `open` operation itself, so I'm not going to delve into that.

Comment: Well explained in beginner's language.. I came here to write a simple answer to this question, but your answer is just perfect!!

Answer (score 7):

At the core of it when opening for reading nothing fancy actually *needs* to happen. All it needs to do is check the file exists and the application has enough privileges to read it and create a handle on which you can issue read commands to the file.

It's on those commands that actual reading will get dispatched.

The OS will often get a head start on reading by starting a read operation to fill the buffer associated with the handle. Then when you actually do the read it can return the contents of the buffer immediately rather then needing to wait on disk IO.

For opening a new file for write the OS will need to add a entry in the directory for the new (currently empty) file. And again a handle is created on which you can issue the write commands.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, a call to open needs to find the file, and then record whatever it needs to so that later I/O operations can find it again. That's quite vague, but it will be true on all the operating systems I can immediately think of. The specifics vary from platform to platform. Many answers already on here talk about modern-day desktop operating systems. I've done a little programming on CP/M, so I will offer my knowledge about how it works on CP/M (MS-DOS probably works in the same way, but for security reasons, it is not normally done like this today).

On CP/M you have a thing called the FCB (as you mentioned C, you could call it a struct; it really is a 35-byte contiguous area in RAM containing various fields). The FCB has fields to write the file-name and a (4-bit) integer identifying the disk drive. Then, when you call the kernel's Open File, you pass a pointer to this struct by placing it in one of the CPU's registers. Some time later, the operating system returns with the struct slightly changed. Whatever I/O you do to this file, you pass a pointer to this struct to the system call.

What does CP/M do with this FCB? It reserves certain fields for its own use, and uses these to keep track of the file, so you had better not ever touch them from inside your program. The Open File operation searches through the table at the start of the disk for a file with the same name as what's in the FCB (the '?' wildcard character matches any character). If it finds a file, it copies some information into the FCB, including the file's physical location(s) on the disk, so that subsequent I/O calls ultimately call the BIOS which may pass these locations to the disk driver. At this level, specifics vary.

Answer (score -8):

In simple terms, when you open a file you are actually requesting the operating system to load the desired file  ( copy the contents of file ) from the secondary storage to ram for processing. And the reason behind this ( Loading a file ) is because you cannot process the file directly from the Hard-disk because of its extremely slow speed compared to Ram.

The open command will generate a system call which in turn copies the contents of the file from the secondary storage ( Hard-disk ) to Primary storage ( Ram ).

And we 'Close' a file because the modified contents of the file has to be reflected to the original file which is in the hard-disk. :)

Hope that helps.